# In SQL Server, use a regex in SQL statement to extract a subset of a column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that has result date data in two different columns. The desired outcome is to output a single column with the date that is either extracted from the `Result` column or is the date from the `ResultDate` column.

| Result | ResultDate |
| --- | --- |
| Test | 5/1/2017 |
| Test | 9/12/2014 |
| Test, completed 8/4/2020 |  |
| Test, 5/5/2011 |  |

My first thought was to do something like this...

```
select coalesce(
   regex('\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2,4}',Result),
   ResultDate
) as ResultDate
from Table
```

...but I can't find any info on using regex like this. All the posts talk about using regular expressions in the `where` clause, not in a column specification.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support Regex (natively). If you must use Regex in SQL Server, you need to use a CLR Function.

Comment: Is the "date" (i use that term loosely for good reason here) always the last "word" in the `Result` column? Are the dates always in the same format `d/m/yyyy`/`m/d/yyyy` (impossible to tell from the data)?

Comment: The date could be anywhere in the result field. It is child's play for a regex to find it, but it looks like I need to use a CLR.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: *"The date could be anywhere in the result field."* That answers one of the questions I asked in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66874337/in-mssql-use-regex-in-sql-statement-to-extract-a-subset-of-a-field?noredirect=1#comment118211842_66874337) What about the other?

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt to redefine the problem without a regular expression.

*Assumption for sample data*: dates are to be interpreted as `dd/mm/yyyy`.
*Assumption for proposed solution*: `Result` never contains two dates (would require extra logic).

1. [Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) the `Result` column on spaces.
   `cross apply string_split(d.Result, ' ') rs`
2. Look for "words" where a [conversion attempt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) [to the desired format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) is successful.
   `try_convert(date, rs.value, 103) is not null`
3. If SQL Server does unwanted date conversions, then you could add further restrictions along the line of your regular expression. If you *really* want you could add another `string_split` with slashes on the resulting `value` from the first split and evaluate the parts separately...

   `where len(rs.value) - len(replace(rs.value, '/', '')) = 2` --> two slashes
   `where try_convert(int, replace(rs.value, '/', '')) is not null` --> only digits and slashes
   `where len(rs.value) >= 6 and len(rs.value) <= 10` --> length between 6 and 10

**Sample data**

```
create table data
(
  Result nvarchar(100),
  ResultDate date
);

insert into data (Result, ResultDate) values
('Test', '2017-01-05'),
('Test', '2014-12-09'),
('Test, completed 8/4/2020', null), 
('Test, 5/5/2011', null);
```

**Solution**

Base solution:

```
select d.Result,
       coalesce(d.ResultDate, convert(date, rs.value, 103)) as ResultDate
from data d
cross apply string_split(d.Result, ' ') rs -- result split
where coalesce(d.ResultDate, try_convert(date, rs.value, 103)) is not null;
```

Extended solution:

```
select d.Result,
       coalesce(d.ResultDate, convert(date, rs.value, 103)) as ResultDate,
       convert(nvarchar(10), coalesce(d.ResultDate, convert(date, rs.value, 103)), 103) as ResultDate103
from data d
cross apply string_split(d.Result, ' ') rs -- result split
where d.ResultDate is not null
   or (try_convert(date, rs.value, 103) is not null
  and  len(rs.value) - len(replace(rs.value, '/', '')) = 2 -- date string must contain 2 slashes
  and  try_convert(int, replace(rs.value, '/', '')) is not null -- only digits and slashes
  and  len(rs.value) >= 6 and len(rs.value) <= 10); -- date string length filter (d/m/yy --> dd/mm/yyyy)
```

**Result**

`ResultDate103` is only included for the "Extended solution".

```
Result                    ResultDate  ResultDate103
------------------------  ----------  -------------
Test                      2017-01-05  05/01/2017
Test                      2014-12-09  09/12/2014
Test, completed 8/4/2020  2020-04-08  08/04/2020
Test, 5/5/2011            2011-05-05  05/05/2011
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=89a994fe3f6f0cc28f4b4052ee9078ea) to see things in action with intermediate steps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after more digging I found my answer...patindex.

```
select
replace(cast(coalesce(
        iif(patindex('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]%', [Result])<>0
            ,substring([result],patindex('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]%', [Result]),10) 
            ,null) 
      ,[Satisfied Date]) as date),'-','') as resultDate
from Table
```

It is a little clunky, but it does exactly what I want it to.